# Filtering Excel for cell values of specific length and attributes

Tags: excel

What is the best way to filter out cell values in a large Excel spreadsheet (over 20,000 lines) for ONLY numeric values that are 6 digits in length, do not contain letters, and are sometimes stored as text.
The cell values may also contain:
-special characters and/or letters 
-may have preceding or leading zeroes (stored as text to retain the zeroes)
-up to 30 digits (characters, numbers, letters)
I have tried the functions LEN, ISNUMBER, ISERROR 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter out"?  What do you mean by "I have tried the functions..."?

Comment: Autofilter on 6 chars first then keep going?

Comment: Thank you for the great feedback. Let me clarify. There are potentially 83000 rows of records. The records should all be assigned identifiers that are 6 digits (i.e. 000001, 170890...) Identifiers with leading zeroes should be kept. However there are identifiers in this list that are alphanumeric, contain special characters, <> 6 digits. What would be the best way to filter this list so that I know which identifiers are only 6 numeric digits and how many are not (or need to be corrected)? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
IF(ISNUMBER(A1+0), LEN(A1+0) = 6)
```

It will implicitly convert anything that can be number to a *proper* number (i.e. no leading zeros) and see if that's 6 characters long otherwise return false.

If it's possible to do the filtering in Google Sheets you can use regula rexpressions which will make the whole thing a lot easier, espcially if you want to measure the lenght of numbers including their leading zeros.
Once you paste the data you can use `=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A1:A,"^(?:\D*)(\d{6})$"))`.
This will return true for any six digit number (including leading zeros) that is preceded by anything that is not a number.

Comment: @pnuts I assume those shan't be considered numbers, otherwise if "fda564" should be interpreted as 564 you also need to ask if "fda654gd89" should be interpreted as a number. In this case neither will be and it will return false. My understanding was OP wants to retrieve only those cells that are numbers while some may not be as he said the values to be filtered should not contain letters. ("ONLY numeric values that are 6 digits in length, do not contain letters, and are sometimes stored as text.")

Comment: I see. If OP wants any cell that contains six consecutive digits it's probably faster to copypaste into Google Sheets and run regexmatch.

Comment: I'm not familiar with google sheets. Can you explain further? Also, since the list I am working with contains leading zeroes, the only way I knew to retain them in the spreadsheet cells was to format as text. Make sense? Thanks.

Comment: I expanded my answer, please take a look and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and post an update.

Comment: Does this need to be done in Google sheets? Will it work just in 'Excel'?

Comment: Does this need to be done in Google sheets? Will it work just in 'Excel'? I wasn't able to get it to work. When I pasted the data, the leading zeroes didn't transfer.  I retained the zeroes when I formatted the A column as 'plain text' before I pasted the data successfully. Then I selected column A, hit key F2, clicked on cell C1,  pasted the array formula above in formula bar, pressed ctrl+shift+enter. The results in column c all read 'false'. ??? Please help. Dealing with preceding zeroes in excel was an issue in our old tracking system too so any advice would be so appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Excel doesn't have Regex functions, you'd have to build something in VBA for that. Can you provide a few examples? The formula above worked for all examples I could come up with. Thanks